# highstocks chart showing extra month

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am having in issue in using the highstock charting js library. It seems that there is an extra x-axis tick showing up in the chart. I have tried setting the xAxis max and ceiling properties:

```
  "xAxis": {
    "ordinal": false,
    "max": 1459400300000,
    "ceiling": 1459400300000,
    "type": "datetime",
    "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
        "day": "%b %e",
        "week": "%b %e",
        "month": "%b %Y",
        "year": "Y"
    }
},
```

I have created a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwcvzwse/18/) that replicates the issue, which is that there is an 'Apr 2016' tick showing with no data. Even though none of the series data has a js time stamp that is in April. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Also, make sure to extend the chart fairly wide and you can see the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just remove `"max": 1459400300000`, that would be fine.

Comment: That seemed to do it, thanks a lot. see [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwcvzwse/19/)